Proof of theorem 10.4.8 (Bogachev's Measure Theory)
I was studying chapter 10 (about disintegration) of Bogachev's Measure Theory, and I'm actually stuck on a sentence in the proof of theorem 10.4.8.
For the context, it is needed the following definition:

Then, the theorem 10.4.8 is the following:

And the first part of the proof is the following:

The problem for me is the sentence

This means that for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$, one has a $\mathcal{E}$-measurable function $\eta (A,y)$ such that $\mu^\mathcal{B}(A,x)=\eta (A,\pi (x))$.

I really don't understand how can he say that: it is clear to me that for general functions this is definitely not true. I mean, if we have $f:X\rightarrow Z,\ g:X\rightarrow Y$ we cannot conclude that there exists $h:Y\rightarrow Z$ such that $f=h\circ g$: we can have for example $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$ and $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$, and $h(g(x_1))=h(g(x_2))$ is a contradiction if $f=h\circ g$.
So this means that in this case there is some hidden property (at least to me) that allows this type of composition to work. For example, in this context it is not possible that there exists $x_1,x_2 \in X$ such that $\mu^\mathcal{B}(A,x_1)\neq \mu^\mathcal{B}(A,x_2)$ and $\pi(x_1)=\pi(x_2)$.
So my question is, how can the sentence in the blockquote be justified? Why can we construct such $\eta$?

Measurability w.r.t. $\mathcal B$ is equivalent to composition with $\pi$ of an $\mathcal E-$ measrable function. Verify this for simple functions and then take limits.
